# RPC shutdown command from Linux to Windows Server 2012 - connection refused

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, rpc, net

I am needing to restart a windows server from a Linux server.

The error i get is: (i have replaced ip address with xx )

```
Could not connect to server xx.xx.xx.xx
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

It fails with that result no matter what. The commands i have tried are:

```
net rpc shutdown -I xx.xx.xx.xx -f -U user%password

net rpc shutdown -I xx.xx.xx.xx -f -U domain/user%password

net rpc shutdown -f -I xx.xx.xx.xx -W domain.local -U user%password
```

I have also tried taking out the password, after executing the command it then asks for a password. If I type the password in it still fails with the NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

It is the Administrator account I'm trying to login with.

I have temp disabled firewall altogether for a second while testing.

Very lost and its driving me mad. Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Linux you are using ? Newer OS restricted the lmhash and such security (you can lower it thougth in the windows)

Comment: im using centos 5.5... much older and still capable of it. Its not the linux side. its definetely the win server 2012 blocking it

Comment: check your security log on the server then

Comment: now im getting an error of: Connection failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

i have checked logs and cant find anything related